# How to find out if application is running on tablet or mobile device in android?

Tags: android, xml, graphics, tablet

I am developing an android application which is compatible for mobile screen and tablet screen both.

So I am creating 4 different screens for each. That is

1. `login_portrait.xml`
2. `login_landscape.xml`
3. `login_portrait_large.xml`
4. `login_landscape.xml`

But the problem is that how to find that my application used by any user is using tablet or mobile?

Is there any solution?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet

Answer (score 2):

I use this method:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context mContext){
    return (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

and it will be enough, if returns false then your device is a mobile phone.

More info: 
[How to detect device is Android phone or Android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet)

Comment: Is there any need to change in XML layout file dear?

Comment: I have used the method using xml layouts or storing a variable in resources <resources> but that will be incorrect, every day we have mobile phone devices with different resolutions and this cannot be accomplished for certain devices.

Comment: Yup I am facing the same problem. But my requirement is my app should run on mobile screen and tablet screen without overlapping. Is there any other soulution?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieved this by [Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support). Put the different .xml layout files in the following `res` folders specifically and android will do it for you.

```
res/layout-small/login.xml             // login layout for small portrait
res/layout-normal/login.xml             // login layout for normal portrait
res/layout-normal-land/login.xml       // login layout for normal land
res/layout-large/login.xml        // login layout for large portrait
res/layout-large-land/login.xml    // login layout for large land
```

You can just use the login.xml and android will choose the proper one for you.

Note. for android 3.2 or higher, a new  configuration qualifiers system is used. You can read [more](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)  about it from the official develop guide.

EDIT:
 BTW, each screen size is defined as:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

They can be overlapped sometime, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview) for more info.

Comment: I had already done it. bt i dont know how to findout that screen is large or small

Comment: If you do care about if the screen size is small (default is not enough), you can create a new layout folder called `layout-small`

Comment: I had already done the same. the problem is that how to fetch the size of the screen in the coading/

Comment: no need for the screen size. i want that my application run on the medium and large screen both.

Comment: @NiravDabhi Medium? You mean 7 inch tablets or the phones?

Comment: Finally, I get your question.If you want to know this programmatically, I thinke @Glenn's answer quite matches your need.

Comment: ya i think so. ya and android phone doesn't have small screens i think. so normal screen is not the problem if i use scroll view. but the problem is in large screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can put XML (bools.xml) files in the following folders

1. `values-large`
2. `values-xlarge`
3. `values-normal`
4. `values-small`

For `values-large/bools.xml` and `values-xlarge/bools.xml`

```
<bool name="tablet">true</bool>
```

For `values-normal/bools.xml` and `values-small/bools.xml`

```
<bool name="tablet">false</bool>
```

Then to determine programmatically,

```
boolean isTablet = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.tablet);
```

Comment: Is there any need to change in layout of screen?

Comment: @NiravDabhi No need .

Comment: Good to know! Please Mark the check button :)

Comment: Sir my problem is when i run that on tablet my app is stop unfortunately!

Comment: Oh. Can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include a bit more info in your question.

Are you collecting data dependent on whether it's a mobile or tablet? If so, you may want to use Javascript to detect the resolution[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520186/how-to-detect-tablet-mobile-desktop-tv-using-javascript)

That, or you can just detect the "user-agent".

If you need to make the application a bit more responsive contingent on the browser-type, than try twitter-bootstrap:
[twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

Comment: First i had create the design which is suitable for mobile screen then i test that on tablet which is not suitable. so i create four design of the application.

Comment: Ok, I understand. If you need to create more of a responsive application, I'd look into implementing a "web view" app:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

This is more or less how it's done professionally nowadays. Your android app will point to a URL, load it, and it can be interactive with your native android application via Javascript.

Then, you can use Javascript libraries such as Twitter-Bootstrap to handle responsiveness based on the resolution of your browser.

I don't know if this may help for your current implementation, but you may eventually need to do this.

Comment: Web View is not the solution sir. its best option when we load the data from URL. but how to implement when we have numbers of widgets.

Comment: Ok sir. i am trying as u suggested it will need major changes in my app.

Comment: I understand it may not be the best solution for what you are attempting to accomplish.

But the pros of the suggested implementation is that it is platform-agnostic, and you can make changes to your styling and CSS based on whether you app is web-based, Android, Windows or iOS based.

And although your app may need some major changes, the suggested solution may really help in the long run in regards to scalability and re-useability.

Cons is that you may have to depend on cached data if there is no connection available to your server.

Regardless, I hope this info helps one way or another.

Comment: Ok sir. I think so. But mostly my app doesnt need web view. Its all about web services.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

You can also have it in a **Base** `class` and make it protected that way you can reuse it in all the activities that extend your **base** `class`.