# Detecting website access through tablets

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tablet, device-detection

I am a newbie .NET developer. I have a website wherein I need to detect whether access to the website is from a TABLET. There is a mobile version of the site but my client wants it such that when the site is accessed through a tablet, a modified version of the main site should appear instead of the mobile site. Thus I need to detect access **specifically** from tablets. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you please remove the duplicate tag? Is that going to mess with the answers that I might get if it isn't there? My question deals with detecting access from tablets and only tablets and not rest of the mobile device such as mobile phones. Also I cannot use the third party tool suggested.

Comment: The exact same techniques used for other mobile devices are also used for tablets. More than one technique was suggested in the answers to the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [51Degrees mobi](http://51degrees.com/Products/Device-Detection), which does a redirect if it detects a mobile device. There's a free version available (less configurable), but please see the [overview for a comparison](http://51degrees.com/Products/Device-Detection/Compare-Device-Data).

Comment: I cannot use any third party tool, is there any other option such as using the display size or something?

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to detect mobile device and then redirect to other link.

As like following to detect mobile devices

```
if (!RegExp(" Mobile/").test(navigator.userAgent)) 
{
   // redirect to your old site.
}
```

For user agent string see following link that may help you.
[How to detect tablet, mobile, desktop, tv using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520186/how-to-detect-tablet-mobile-desktop-tv-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Abid, but the problem here is that I need to isolate tablets, the mobile redirection stuff is already implemented such that it redirects to the mobile page